# ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression in 12.1.0.2

Tags: sql, oracle

We are in 12.1.0.2 db and i am getting below errors while running the query. Please give some feedback.

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select A.COLUMN_LABEL,B.HOST_NAME AS HOST,B.TARGET_NAME AS DATABASE,B.STATU
S AS CURRENT_STATUS, B.TABLESPACE_NAME AS TS_NAME,round(sum(B.file_size/(1024*10
24*1024)),2) AS CURRENT_SIZE,
  2  B.AUTOEXTENSIBLE AS TYPE_TS,case when autoextensible ='YES' then round(sum(
max_file_size/(1024*1024*1024)),2) ELSE NULL END AS TOTAL_MAX_SIZE,to_number(A.v
alue)/1024 as value
  3  FROM SYSMAN.MGMT$METRIC_CURRENT A,SYSMAN.MGMT$DB_DATAFILES_ALL B,sysman.mgm
t$db_tablespaces C
  4  where a.column_label in ( 'Tablespace Used Space (MB)')
  5      and a.target_type in( 'rac_database','oracle_database')
  6      and a.target_type =b.target_type
  7      AND A.TARGET_TYPE=C.TARGET_TYPE
  8      AND B.TARGET_TYPE=C.TARGET_TYPE
  9     AND B.STATUS IN('ONLINE')
 10    AND A.TARGET_NAME=B.TARGET_NAME
 11    AND A.TARGET_NAME=C.TARGET_NAME
 12    AND B.TARGET_NAME=C.TARGET_NAME
 13  GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
 14* ORDER BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
SQL> /
select A.COLUMN_LABEL,B.HOST_NAME AS HOST,B.TARGET_NAME AS DATABASE,B.STATUS AS
CURRENT_STATUS, B.TABLESPACE_NAME AS TS_NAME,round(sum(B.file_size/(1024*1024*10
24)),2) AS CURRENT_SIZE,
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

Comment: `GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8` syntaxt is not supported by Oracle. You must copy the selected columns in GROUP BY clause.

Comment: The group by seems incorrect, why would you want to group by all, when you are doing a sum, I guess you might want to try `Group by A.COLUMN_LABEL, B.HOST_NAME, B.TARGET_NAME, B.STATUS, 
B.TABLESPACE_NAME, B.AUTOEXTENSIBLE, to_number(A.value)/1024`

Answer (score 0):

Group by an ordinal is not enabled by default. You have to set _sql_compatibility to 1

```
  select deptno, sum(sal)
  from emp
  group by 1
  order by 1
SQL> /
select deptno, sum(sal)
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

alter session set "_sql_compatibility"=1

Session altered.

select deptno, sum(sal)
from emp
group by 1
order by 1

SQL> /

    DEPTNO   SUM(SAL)
---------- ----------
        10       8750
        20      10875
        30       9400
```

Comment: Note that `_sql_compatibility ` is a so-called "underscore parameter" which means it is undocumented and should not be used in production code unless Oracle Support tell you to. In this case it probably won't do any harm, it's just best to understand what's happening.

Comment: This one is safe to use.